# How to tell the maximum data alignment requirement in C++

Tags: c++, alignment, alignof

Referencing this question and answer [Memory alignment : how to use alignof / alignas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17091382/memory-alignment-how-to-use-alignof-alignas) "Alignment is a restriction on which memory positions a value's first byte can be stored." Is there a portable way in C++ to find out the highest granularity of alignment that is required for instructions not to fault (for example in ARM)?  Is `alignof(intmax_t)` sufficient since its the largest integer primitive type?

Further, how does something in malloc align data to a struct's boundaries?  For example if I have a struct like so

```
alignas(16) struct SomethingElse { ... };
```

the `SomethingElse` struct is required to be aligned to a boundary that is a multiple of 16 bytes. Now if I request memory for a struct from malloc like so

```
SomethingElse* ptr = malloc(sizeof(SomethingElse));
```

Then what happens when malloc returns a pointer that points to an address like `40`?  Is that invalid since the pointer to `SomethingElse` objects must be a multiple of 16?

Comment: If you are going to ask *Is there a portable way in C++[...]* why tag the question with C?

Comment: @NathanOliver my mistake...

Comment: @nwp but won't the alignment be the same as the largest datatype in the struct?

Comment: @nwp Ah, any way I can change the alignment of the struct to be 16 then?  I guess the alignment for any datatype (class or struct) then is going to be the largest primitive alignment required on the system?

Comment: @nwp because the `alignas` keyword does that right?  Then there must be a way to do that without using `alignas` also?

Comment: Are you looking for `std::max_align_t`, by any chance?

Comment: If you read the documenation **carefully**. you might find the type dedicated to this.

Comment: Wait, maybe I was talking garbage. `alignas` should tell the compiler that `SomethingElse` is 16-byte aligned. That makes the largest member of whatever has a `SomethingElse` also at least 16 bytes. I do remember a caveat that neither `malloc` nor `new` are required to actually give you over-aligned memory though. Not sure if that got fixed.

Comment: @nwp how even would one go about fixing that?  There is no way to tell malloc the alignment that you want right?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks!  And yes Olaf I should have read documentation more carefully, I would have seen it.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Do you want to post an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: `malloc` might already give you 16-byte aligned memory for efficiency reasons. Otherwise you are kind of screwed. Writing a wrapper that returns properly aligned memory by allocating more than necessary will work fine, but `free`ing that memory is not so easy because you need to restore the original pointer which you will need to keep somewhere.

Comment: As a sidenote: you want the **maximum** alignment requirement, not the minimum.

Comment: @Olaf i meant "minimum alignment requirement that doesn't cause a fault"

Comment: @Curious: Which would be the _maximum_ alignment **requirement**! Which is reflected by the name of the type, which does not read `min_align_t` (that would be `char` by definition).

Comment: @Curious `There is no way to tell malloc the alignment that you want right?` Right, but you can tell `std::aligned_alloc` when that is available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for [`std::max_align_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/max_align_t)

Answer (score 3):

> How to tell the maximum data alignment requirement in C++

There is `std::max_align_t` which

> is a POD type whose alignment requirement is at least as strict (as large) as that of every scalar type.

Vector instructions may use array operands that require a higher alignment than any scalar. I don't know if there is a portable way to find out the the upper bound for that.

To find the alignment requirement for a particular type, you can use `alignof`.

---

> Further, how does something in malloc align data to a struct's boundaries?

`malloc` aligns to some boundary that is enough for any scalar. In practice exactly the same as `std::max_align_t`.

It won't align correctly for "overaligned" types. By overaligned, I mean a type that has higher alignment requirement than `std::max_align_t`.

> Then what happens when malloc returns a pointer that points to an address like 40?

Dereferencing such `SomethingElse*` would be have undefined behaviour.

> Is that invalid since the pointer to SomethingElse objects must be a multiple of 16?

Yes.

---

> how even would one go about fixing that? There is no way to tell malloc the alignment that you want right?

To allocate memory for overaligned types, you need `std::aligned_alloc` which is to be introduced in C++17.

Until then, you can use platform specific functions like `posix_memalign` or you can over allocate with `std::malloc` (allocate the alignment - 1 worth of extra bytes), then use `std::align` to find the correct boundary. But then you must keep track of both the start of the buffer, and the start of the memory block separately.

Comment: According to [aligned_alloc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/aligned_alloc) reference, it's part of C++11 (or I don't understand the meaning of "(since C11)" correctly).

Comment: @Rotem C11 is a C language standard :) cppreference is a refrence for both C and C++.