# aligned_malloc() vs alignas() for Constant Buffers

Tags: malloc, direct3d11, alignas

In C++, we have the keyword `alignas(n)` and we have the `_aligned_malloc(m,n)` function.
`alignas` works on the type while `aligned_malloc` works on whatever you call it.
Can I use `alignas(16)` to fullfil the 16-byte alignment requirement for Direct3D Constant Buffers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could use it like this:

```
struct SceneConstantBuffer
{
    alignas(16) DirectX::XMFLOAT4X4 ViewProjection[2];
    alignas(16) DirectX::XMFLOAT4 EyePosition[2];
    alignas(16) DirectX::XMFLOAT3 LightDirection{};
    alignas(16) DirectX::XMFLOAT3 LightDiffuseColor{};
    alignas(16) int NumSpecularMipLevels{ 1 };
};
```

What won't work is `__declspec(align)`...

**EDIT**: If you want to use it on the struct itself something similar to this should work too:

```
struct alignas(16) SceneConstantBuffer
{
    DirectX::XMMATRIX ViewProjection; // 16-bytes
    ...
    DirectX::XMFLOAT3 LightDiffuseColor{};
}
```

Comment: Can I use `alignas(16)` on `SceneConstantBuffer` or do i have to use it on every member?

Comment: @Raildex: Yes, see edit. You'll want to check it though when you initialize it with an assert.

Comment: Thank you! One more question: Do the members of a constant buffer need to be aligned or only the constant buffer itself?

Comment: @Raildex: Yes, there still needs to be alignment, so often padding is used to make up for the difference if needed. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21150698/499581), it should be able to give you some idea what is at work, cheers!